How to automatically cache NFS files on macOS Sonoma?
Is it possible to automatically cache files from an NFS server locally?
I'm connected to the NFS server over a fairly low bandwidth link.  Most of the files on the server change rarely.  It would greatly help if files could be automatically cached locally.
I've looked at a bunch of man pages, but found nothing appropriate for macOS.
